# Liferay + Glassfish 3.1.1 Location of portal-ext.properties file?

Tags: liferay

Where does the portal-ext.properties file go before the liferay war file is deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically the folder where your appserver resides. if I remember correctly, glassfish typically has two nested "glassfish" folder - there it'd be within the first.

The best way to explore that yourself (and to be sure) is to put your portal-ext.properties in every location you guess it might be, then startup the server and examine the log. There it mentions which file is being read.

Also, AFAIK portal-ext.properties will also be read from the user's home directory if found there - careful, when you run a server like glassfish, that might be a different user account than your own.

Answer (score -1):

domains/domain1/applications/liferay-portal/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar >>> /content/
you will find all translation files there.