# Where does the Liferay portal-ext.properties go in Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, liferay, liferay-6

Below is my Liferay path:

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\liferay\applications
```

Comment: For temporal storage (may disappear on re-deploy) place the file at `/j2ee-modules/liferay-portal/WEB-INF/classes` folder under your given path.

Comment: @mico part of the install requires you to create a portal-ext.properties but i don't know where to place it?

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363910 ?

Comment: Or different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490877/where-does-the-liferay-portal-ext-properties-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is was the correct place to place it in my liferay 6 install:
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\liferay\applications\liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2-20110727\WEB-INF\classes

Answer (score 2):

`C:\glassfish3` and there should be the `deploy` directory in the same place.  The `data` directory is there if you are still using hsql.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it goes here: `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\liferay\lib\classes`

You should not put this in the exploded classes directory, because if you ever upgrade or undeploy/redeploy, that will get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Try if you find location:

`C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\liferay\src\main\resources\portal-ext.properties`

to put your file into.

**Edit:**
Look for your `portal.properties` file, find there liferay.home variable. Check that path and place the file there. Another is that what I said in my comments.

*This tip was on [liferay](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3307924) pages.*

Comment: the folder src does not exist.

Comment: another solution would be to explode Liferay's war and put the portal-ext.properties in WEB-INF/classes, hacky but working solution AFAIR when I was using LR 5.1.2